# Finding affected rows

Tags: mysql

How do I know how many rows were affected by an update query?

```
mysql> update todel set name = 'xyz' where id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select mysql_affected_rows();
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION test.mysql_affected_rows does not exist
```

I want to use this function in stored procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

> ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted
>   by the last statement if it was an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT. For
>   other statements, the value may not be meaningful.